# Custom Sequence Using ReactiveMongoOperation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, mongorepository

I am new to reactive programming and i am trying to implement a custom id in my mongodb  collection. I saw we could implement it using mongoOperation but I am using ReactiveMongoOperation,
so how can I built my NextSequence Class?

```
@Service
public class NextSequenceService {

@Autowired
private ReactiveMongoOperations reactiveMongoOperations;


public int getNextSequence(String seqName)
{
    CustomSequences counter = reactiveMongoOperations.findAndModify(
        query(where("_id").is(seqName)),
        new Update().inc("seq",1),
        options().returnNew(true).upsert(true),
        CustomSequences.class);
    return counter.getSeq();
}
}
```

This Code is not working it is an MongoOperation snippet

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me:

```java
public long generateSequence(String seqName) {
    Mono<UserSequence> counter = mongoOperations.findAndModify(query(where("_id").is(seqName)),
            new Update().inc("seq",1), options().returnNew(true).upsert(true),
            UserSequence.class);
    return !Objects.isNull(counter) ? counter.block().getSeq() : 1;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).